# How can i enable the rollback feature when one of the action fail in the 'installation screen'

Tags: install4j

How can i enable the rollback feature when one the of the action fail in the 'installation screen'.

In my case 'installation screen' contains around 10 action along with 'install files action'. I want to rollback to previous version if any action failure.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The rollback feature is always enabled. install4j has "rollback barriers" that stop rollback at a specific action or screen once they have completed successfully.

By default, the "Installation" screen has its "Rollback barrier" property selected, so if an action on the "Installation" screen fails and there is no other rollback barrier (screen or action), everything will be rolled back.

Comment: I added first action 'stop service' in the "Installation" screen and followed by other actions. When i am testing rollback feature, service not started automatically.

Comment: Indeed, that particular action is not rolled back. I've added it to our issue tracker.

Comment: Extract a zip file and registry action also not rolled back. is this intentional?

Comment: What is the best way to rollback 'stop service' and Extract a zip actions ?

Comment: Stop service cannot be rolled back at this time. Instead of "Extract zip", use "Install contents of ZIP file" action.

Comment: What about registry Add/Remove action rollback ?

Comment: It can roll back.

Comment: Rollback working as expected with "Install contents of ZIP file" action.